# How do I get the system proxy using Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, proxy

I have the following code that I am trying to extract the systems proxy settings from:

```
QList<QNetworkProxy> listOfProxies = QNetworkProxyFactory::systemProxyForQuery();
foreach ( QNetworkProxy loopItem, listOfProxies ) {
    qDebug() << "proxyUsed:" << loopItem.hostName();
}
```

I only get one item back and with a blank host name.  Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: What does loopItem.type() show? Smells like "no proxy" (type 2) which occurs when Qt can't find the proxy (see their docs for the proxy factory's limitations).

Comment: It shows type 2 as you state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By putting:

```
QNetworkProxyQuery npq(QUrl("http://www.google.com"));
QList<QNetworkProxy> listOfProxies = QNetworkProxyFactory::systemProxyForQuery(npq);
```

I appear get the proxy out.

Answer (score 1):

QNetworkProxyQuery npq(QUrl(**QLatin1String**("http://www.google.com")));

Don't forget to use QLatin1String :)

Comment: Not an answer. No explanation given why to use QLatin1String. Why not QStringLiteral? etc..