# QNetworkProxyFactory::systemProxyForQuery() is not reflecting changes to system proxy settings

Tags: qt, proxy

In Qt, I'm trying to use the system proxy settings. This seems to work well, as long as I do not change them while the application is open.

Once I change the system proxy settings, I've got to close and re-open my application to pick up the new proxy settings.

This is documented in this bug here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-3470

Is there any known work-around for this issue? Is this solved in newer versions of Qt (the listed bug was filed against Qt 4.5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could peek at the System Registry values for the system proxy. This is quite straightforward (from what I understand) as Qt has the QSettings api which will give you quick access to the registry.

Check this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819961) out for some info on the registry values.

Check this [link](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.5/qsettings.html#accessing-the-windows-registry-directly) out for some info/examples of QSettings.

Comment: It's not really an ideal solution, but I think it may be the closest we'll be able to get until Trolltech offers something better...

Comment: It is sort of a round about way of doing something relatively simple but where this is a will there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

From [How do I get the system proxy using Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932824/how-do-i-get-the-system-proxy-using-qt)

```
QNetworkProxyQuery npq(QUrl("http://www.google.com"));
QList<QNetworkProxy> listOfProxies = QNetworkProxyFactory::systemProxyForQuery(npq);
```

Comment: I haven't checked with newer versions of Qt, but my issues was that changes made to the system proxy while the application was running wouldn't be reflected in this list.